# undefined local variable or method `on' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fd3b4516a00>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to replace the edit action of a controller with one having an extra parameter, but am getting:

```
undefined local variable or method `on' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fd3b4516a00>
```

Here is the routes.rb section:

```
resources :structures, except: :edit do
  get '/:doctype' => :edit, on: :edit
end
```

The issue is :edit. Using another action like :new works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this instead:

```
resources :structures, except: :edit do
  get '/edit/:doctype' => :edit
end
```

The syntax you've tried to use is intended to be used with `on: (new|member|collection)`. `edit` is not a valid option here.

Comment: You also see OP's error if you mistype "member". Double check your spelling!